# Application start is not getting called in asp.Net application with Servicestack 4 and F#

Tags: asp.net, f#, servicestack, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

I was trying asp.net host with servicestack application. Here is link to my [repo](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackFSharp/tree/master/V4)

Without servicestack global.asax.fs 's application start is getting called but it is not getting called with servvicestak installed. I have successfully made it work with V3.71 and also with self host. But asp.net host with servicestack V4 it is breaking even before getting into application start. And error is coming that instance of AppHost is not created, so servicestack could not start. That is also making difficult to debug it.

Please have a look and at least provide a way to start debugging. Or a something I can start with to look into.

Please let me know if any further detail is required.

Comment: I noticed in your [packages.config](https://github.com/kunjee17/ServiceStackFSharp/blob/master/V4/ServicestackAspNetHost/ServicestackAspNetHost/packages.config) dependencies you have a mix of old and new dlls, can you try updating your NuGet dependencies so they use the latest versions?

Comment: @mythz thanks for reply... I ll check it and let you know.

Comment: @mythz :( no luck. I have changed a global.asax.fs code a little bit. and also have added details of last finding. Hope that may help. BTW thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a closer look at the source code, it's missing an `ignore()` statement and the end of **Application_Start** because the method is expected to return void (and `apphost.Init()` in **v4** returns a ServiceStackHost so it can be chained), e.g:

```
type Global() = 
    inherit System.Web.HttpApplication()
    member x.Application_Start (sender:Object, e:EventArgs) = 
        let apphost = new App_Start.AppHost()
        apphost.Init() 
        ignore()
```

Comment: thanks man... for solving the issue. Thanks a lot, specifically for helping me with my dumb and silly mistake.

Comment: @kunjee np :) glad it was an easy one - and many thanks for your work on SS + F# templates!